# Pattern Matching for query the number in the log

Tags: java, regex

My program will read a portion of the extracted log file which will look like the following

```
2017-05-30 14:33:43,876 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - SSH: Failed login attempt on [172.16.8.1]. Username: "rene1".
```

but this is not all the things I needed for further process. I only interested with `172.16.8.1` where I will write it into a text file. Because I only need those different IP address. May I know what type of pattern I need to set to make it works. I had set up the pattern but it's seen like not working well 
 This is my pattern for the regular expression `Pattern pat1 = Pattern.compile("(?<=[)[\\d.]+.");`

Comment: Try this: `(?<=\\[)[\\d.]+(?=\\])`. Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/lyPfde/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use next expression : `\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b` for finding an ip address.

Comment: There is one side effect - this regexp chooses all the numbers. So the IP-code 999.999.999.999 will be chosen as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex to match your IP address :

```
private static final String IPADDRESS_PATTERN
        = "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\."
        + "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\."
        + "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\."
        + "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "2017-05-30 14:33:43,876 INFO [SSHD-TRANSFER-1] com.tumbleweed.st.server.sshd.AuthenticationProviderImpl - SSH: Failed login attempt on [172.16.8.1]. Username: \"rene1\".";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(IPADDRESS_PATTERN);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
172.16.8.1
```

---

You can take a look about the regex here [How to validate IP address with regular expression](https://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-ip-address-with-regular-expression/)